# ios-save nsdictionary in nsuserdefault

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

i want to save a nsdictionary have value null in nsuserdefault and don't need replace and delete value null

How?
My code -> impossible save in nsuserdefault

```
NSMutableArray * _itemsNames;
NSString * itemsFilename;

- (void) responseArray:(NSMutableArray *)array {
    [_itemsNames setArray:array];

    [spinner stopAnimating];
    [_itemsNames writeToFile:itemsFilename atomically:YES];
    NSMutableSet *filepathsSet = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"test"];
    [filepathsSet setByAddingObject:itemsFilename];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:filepathsSet forKey:@"test"];
}
```

The json is:(have value null)

```
({
  ID:11,
   name:21-12-2012,
   des:"<null>",
   url: 
     [
       {
         ID:1,
         name: "<null>"
       },
       {
         ID:2,
         name:"<null>"
       }
      ]
},
{
   ID:12,
   name:if i die young,
   des:"<null>",
   url: 
     [
       {
         ID:3,
         name: "<null>"
       },
       {
         ID:21,
         name:"<null>"
       }
      ]
})
```

Comment: what do you want.. save to NSUserDefaul or want to crate a dictinary

Comment: sorry, can you see my update

Answer (score 0):

If you have dictionary `myDict`

Then

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myDict forKey:@"MyDictionary"];
```

`myDict` will be saved only if it contains all objects that implements `NSCoding`

Regarding your null concept.

There is no need to save `nil` values in dictionary for a `key`.
If you try to get an object for a `key` and in dictionary there isn't any object related to that `key` then it will return `nil`. So no need to save `null` values

Comment: Impossible, i can't save json like this in nsuserdefault

Comment: you are not saving json it `NSDictionary`

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean?, my string json return from service has null value

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to store null values in NSDictionary use [NSNull](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Anyway you can just not store key with null value and then for `[mydict objectForKey:@"keyWithNullValue"]` you'll get `nil`.

But as I said if you really really want to store null use something like that:

```
NSSet *mySet = [NSSet setWithObjects:@{
    @"ID":@(11),
    @"name":@"21-12-2012",
    @"des":[NSNull null],
    @"url": @[@{
        @"ID":@(1),
        @"name": [NSNull null]
    }, @{
        @"ID":@(2),
        @"name":[NSNull null]
    }]
},@{
    @"ID":@(12),
    @"name":@"if i die young",
    @"des":[NSNull null],
    @"url": @[@{
        @"ID":@(3),
        @"name": [NSNull null]
    }, @{
        @"ID":@(21),
        @"name":[NSNull null]
    }]}, nil];
```

Comment: I understand you, but json return from service, it can nsstring, nsarray, nsdictionary (i need it's a dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

You mention saving dictionaries, but all you are showing is the JSON representation of an array of dictionaries.

You don't need to do anything strange, take the returned JSON data and turn it into an array and write the array to a plist. Turning it into a string and then trying to make a collection out of it is probably causing you the problems.

Comment: Nope. Because what I'm talking about is elsewhere in your code. Try doing it for yourself first then come back and ask questions.